# How to capture the state of “Translation Progress” for each language within the same Translation Job?

Tags: translation-manager, 2013-sp1-hr1, worldserver

We are using version 2013 SP1 HR1 and sending some Components for translation for multiple languages within the same translation job.

We have written a custom TMS plugin to subscribe to the different state of the Jobs and we are getting it successfully.

However, I have now the requirement to capture/subscribe the events being generated for different tasks within the Translation Job like below:

- Review
- Translate
- Terminated
- Completed

As these states differ in each language, we have sent within the same translation job, I need to implement the custom logic on completion of translation for each language and not for the entire Job.
Is it possible to do with SDL 2013 SP1 HR1, any pointers would be helpful?

Also, as I know SDL Web 8 gives the possibility to subscribe to different events OOB without writing any custom plugin, can this be achieved in SDL Web too without much hassle?

Thnaks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

We wondered something similar some time ago. From memory... it's submitted as a single job/transaction from the Tridion/TMS perspective and within 2013 there's no concept of retrieving 'bits' of the job.

Although this single TMS job/transaction *may* then split into several different workflow processes (depends on the Translation Service you're using) Tridion only retrieves the original, full transaction when notified it's been completed successfully or with errors.

You can see the complexity even in your seemingly simple scenario here - how would "that language service" and then Tridion TMS know which collection of content represented langauge 1 or language 2 in order to deem one language at a specific state whilst another at a different state? And, what would happen if part of the original job was passed back and then there was a blocking issue with another part of the same job?

I've just had a quick look at the docs and see this from [LiveContent](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_TranslationManager_20_SP2/concept_ED712BB908EA4FABB04471038D64300E):

> In Translation Manager 2.0 SP1, the Translation Job remains In Translation until all SDL TMS jobs are either completed or terminated. If the one or more SDL TMS jobs was terminated, the state of the Translation Job is set to Canceled. If all SDL TMS jobs were completed successfully, the Translation Job is set to Completed.

**Consider**:

- Could you manage the specific language collections in a bundle, 
  you could still collate those together in an "install_x_language" bundle if you need to;
- this way you could submit each language separately and
- have an extension that updates the parent bundle metadata
- indicating which languages are complete and
- which are still in translation

... *just a thought*.

## UPDATE

On the suggestion of intercepting the send of the job - I guess the difference is more related to the process in your case etc.

Assuming you have a job being sent that contains translations for multiple languages then intercepting the send is perfectly feasible as we create/send language jobs from within Workflow today for at least one client.

Obviously I don't know your overall process (or if Worfklow is involved) but pay attention to

1. how the editor will see the response to the sending of a job given that you'll *likely* have to fail that specific send transaction (in favour of sending multiple other ones)
2. the fact that the jobs will then come in as and when **each** language is translated - you *may* need some mechanism to alert the original sender when the final translation job comes back so they understand when it's truly complete.

Comment: Thanks Dylan, not sure if I understood the approach completely. I was thinking if we cannot achieve this OOB then to write a custom plugin which will intercept the translation request and then splits into multiple languages jobs, this way from the user perspective they are still launching everything in 1 Job and we will manage the individual job progress from the backend & invoke custom logic accordingly.

Comment: @Yash - updated for some considerations

Comment: Thanks Dylan for your suggestions.  We don't have any custom workflows so far, hence don't see the problem on that front. But for the 2nd point, I am planning to capture the state of individual translation state and notify users along with custom logic.